# My SD Card is write protected..I can't write data to it..Any way to make data writeable?

Tags: android-versions

I just bought a new Samsung Galaxy Core II and guess what it has Android 4.4 Kit Kat which has External SD Card Write Protected Feature..it's very annoying..I can'r write data to External SD Card..nor can delete anything from memory card...!

So please..Any way I can fix it please?

Regards,
Umair Shah